# Find planes parallel to a plane such that the distance from a point is exactly 2 units

Tags: linear-algebra

The exact question is: Determine the two planes parallel to the plane x+2y-3z=5 such that the distance from the point P(1, -3, 6) to the plane is 2 units.

Finding a parallel plane through that point would just be $ (0,2,-3) \cdot (x+1, y-3, z+6) $ right? I need to find the points so I can do that.

I'm not to sure how to go about this one (specifically finding the 2 points 2 units such that it is still parallel). I was trying to take the normal vector of the plane and move the point 2 units along that but that seems to complicated as it would be dividing it by $\sqrt{14}$. I'm not sure if I am going about this right way or if I'm way off.

Any help on what I should be doing?

Thanks

Comment: Sounds to me as if you're doing the right thing.  Just keep going, $\sqrt{14}$ is not all that bad...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the fact that the distance between a plane with equation $ax+by+cz+d=0$ and a point $(x_0, y_0, z_0)$ is given by the formula

$$d = \frac{|ax_0+by_0+cz_0+d|}{a^2 + b^2 + c^2}$$

A general plane parallel to the given one has the form $x+2y-3z+d=0$, so all you need to do is use the formula above to find both values of $d$.